# Bootstrap - Custom CSS within .container, etc not applied

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

Using Bootstrap 3.1.1.

I'm having a little difficulty in styling some elements within bootstrap class'd element.  For instance, I'm trying to get the divs under the "row" class'd div to format with a **custom background color**.  However, bootstrap classes are overriding anything that I have used so far.  The only way that I can get the background color to change so far is by using inline style on the element as shown in the first Div under the "row" Div below.  This indicates to me that there is a problem with specificity.

I've tried quite a few CSS selector to narrow it down, but it seems beyond my knowledge at this point.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
#stovepipe-row div {
    background-color: blue !important;
    border-style: solid;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="stovepipe-row">
        <div style="background-color: yellow" class="col-sm-4 text-center round-corners" id="fuck">
            <h4>This is a Title</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center round-corners">
            <h4>This is a title</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center round-corners">
            <h4>This is a title</h4>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Resolved.  In the CSS file, I was using // incorrected commment syntax instead of /* correct comment syntax */ and css processor was coughing on it.